# css and javascript input form (for date )

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to create  a input form for date like this   (exemple )

[image]

that  gives to user the possibilte to insert just nembers  and it gives him  that  form

```
(___/.___/._________)
```

Comment: Could you use the <input type="date"> tag?

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_date

Comment: look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/vnAb7/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JQuery like this:

```
<input id="date" type="text"></input>

$("#date").mask("99/99/9999");
```

Look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/SEXAj/)